# vb.net string.format exponential (scientific) notation

Tags: vb.net, string, format

Currently I am using the following thing

```
String.format({0,16:e6},freq)
```

But this returns my freq in following notation

```
0.000000e+000
```

I need it to be in

```
0.000000e+00
```

So I need to reducde the exponential factor with one zero less.
Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: To quote the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#EFormatString): `The exponent always consists of a plus or minus sign and a minimum of three digits. The exponent is padded with zeros to meet this minimum, if required.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have figured out on how this can be solved. The comment from @GSerg is correct but there is a workaround.

```
String.format("{0,16:0.000000e+00}",freq)
```

this is how I solved the issue.
Thanks for the support.